# How to disable a trigger before an update statement and enable it again after the update statement in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to disable a trigger before an update statement and enable it again after the update statement in SQL Server?

- Disable trigger
- `Update Table_name set column = 'col' where something`
- Enable Trigger.

How do I write this T-SQL code in SQL Server?

Comment: What code have you tried? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/disable-trigger-transact-sql

Answer (score 5):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DISABLE TRIGGER tr_name
```

update...

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ENABLE TRIGGER tr_name
```

Comment: Note that this is not thread-safe... it works fine in a single-user situation but if there are multiple clients updating a table and invoking the trigger, you could get some unexpected behavior. This is also known as "A global solution to a local problem"

Comment: what is tr_name in this. ?

Comment: That's trigger name